# Layout Inspector - How to find text element's current font

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.2, layout-inspector

After taking a snapshot of the layout and inspecting it with **Layout Inspector**, how do I find what font is used for the selected TextView or AppCompatTextView? Text and Theme property groups have no mentions of `fontFamily` property. However, I see the TextView has a custom font on it.

I'm running Android Studio 3.2.1

Comment: Any update on that?
Android Studio 4.0, I am not able to check the TextView's font using layout inspector.

Comment: @SirKnigget I'm afraid nothing

Answer (score -1):

The only thing i can see about font is the typeface (text -> getTypeFaceStyle(), "bold", "normal" ...)

If the font is defined in styles, you can see the textviews style (theme) in LayoutInspector at the bottom

Comment: Thank you for the reply! My version only lists applied styles but it doesn't show which properties were applied.

Comment: Does not work. Seems that there is no way to see it in the layout inspector